# In C, "getc" reads only three lines from text file

Tags: c, getc

My Code is HERE

```
int main(){
  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen("dic.txt", "r");
  while(getc(fp) != EOF){
    if(getc(fp) == ' '){
        printf("up ");
    }
  }
}
```

My dic.txt is HERE

[dic.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfVPK.png)

my predict is that "up up up up "
because, there are four space " "

but it printed "up "   only one

what is problem?

Comment: Post the text file as text in a code block. Not as a picture.

Comment: @klutt Sorry, forget it, comment deleted. Thanks

Comment: regarding: `while(getc(fp) != EOF){
    if(getc(fp) == ' '){`  This inputs two characters every time through the loop.  Suggest: `int ch; while( (ch = getc(fp)) != EOF){
    if(ch == ' '){`

Comment: regarding: `fp = fopen("dic.txt", "r");`  For robust code, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  Suggest:  `fp = fopen("dic.txt", "r"); if( ! fp ) { perror( "fopen to read dic.txt failed" );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  FILE* fp;
  fp = fopen("dic.txt", "r");
  if (fp == NULL)
  {
    printf("Can't open file\n");
    return 1;
  }

  int ch;                            // int is needed her, not char !!
  while ((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF) {   // read one char and check if it's EOF in one go
    if (ch == ' ') {
      printf("up ");
    }
  }
}
```

- You need to call `getc` once only in the loop, otherwise you skip one out of two characters.
- Bonus: you need to check if `fopen` fails.

Comment: regarding: `printf("Can't open file\n");`  Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  When the error is from a C library function (like 'fopen()') then should also output to `stderr` the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  Suggest calling `perror()` as that outputs both your error message and the text reason.

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `getc` twice per iteration of the loop; one of these two calls compares the character to `EOF`, while the other call compares the character to `' '`.

This has two consequences:

- Your program will only print `"up"` for the spaces which are on even position, and will miss all spaces which are on odd position;
- Your program might make one extra call to `getc` after reaching `EOF` the first time.

**How to fix**

You need to make a *single* call to `getc` per iteration of the loop. Save the character returned by `getc` to a local variable; then use this variable to check for spaces in the body of the loop, *and* to check for `EOF` in the condition of the loop.

Comment: @Jabberwocky What's the point of what? The OP made a mistake when writing their code; two calls to `getc` are done per iteration; only one of these two calls tests for `EOF`, so the first time EOF is reached, it might no be detected and an extra call will be made.

Comment: Forget it, I deleted my pointless comment in the meantime, you can delete your's too

Comment: @Jabberwocky Your comment was not useless. It showed that you misunderstood my explanation. That's a sign that perhaps my explanation was not clear enough.

Comment: No, it was clearly my reading it wrong. The answer is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try Out This Code:

```
FILE *fp;

fp = fopen("dic.txt", "r");
int ch = getc(fp);

while(ch != EOF){
    if(getc(fp) == ' '){
        printf("up ");
    }
}

return 0;
```